# JS Recursion Maximum call stack size exceeded: difference between 2 functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, recursion

I'm working on this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868
My aim is to add a button which on click will draw a new circle and make it move as the 1st one without reseting its cycle. So I've replaced the transition function with this one in order to be able to call it on a specific circle in parameters:

```
function transition2(c){
  c.transition() //Default transition function?
    .duration(10000)
    .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
    .each("end", transition2(c));
}
```

But with this one when i call `transition2(circle);` instead of `transition();` I have a `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I tried to solve this problem with an int which I increment each turn (like if I wanted to do 10 turns).

Why do I have this error with the 2nd function but not in the 1st? What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking transition2 function instead of pass reference to it in 'end' animation listener...

Instead of Mike Bostock's example where he is simply pass reference on to `transition` function:

```
  .each("end", transition);
```

you need a bind callback to referenced function:

```
function transition2(c){
  c.transition() //Default transition function?
    .duration(10000)
    .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
    .each("end", transition2.bind(null, c));
}
```

first argument of `bind` is a reference for `this` but it is not used...

P.S. Thanks to @rioV8 for suggesting of binding a callback, I've missed it in original answer..

Comment: if needed to pass `c` use an arrow function `() => transition2(c)`

Comment: @rioV8 - Or simply bind `c` to the function like what this answer did.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 After I made this comment